# No me funciona la opcion de buscar en jframe

Tags: java

He creado un programa que registra en una base de datos pero al intentar buscar me sale siempre el mensaje de error. Aquí adjunto el código de la ventana.

```
public class frmMaterias extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtldMateria;
    private JTextField txtNombreMateria;


    Connection conexion = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    private void limpiarCuadrosDeTexto() {
        txtldMateria.setText(null);
        txtNombreMateria.setText(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frmMaterias frame = new frmMaterias();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frmMaterias() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblMantenimientoDeMaterias = new JLabel("Mantenimiento de materias");
        lblMantenimientoDeMaterias.setBounds(10, 11, 210, 48);
        contentPane.add(lblMantenimientoDeMaterias);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Id de la materia");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 70, 114, 32);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Nombre de la materia");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 140, 114, 32);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        txtldMateria = new JTextField();
        txtldMateria.setBounds(102, 76, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtldMateria);
        txtldMateria.setColumns(10);

        txtNombreMateria = new JTextField();
        txtNombreMateria.setBounds(122, 146, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtNombreMateria);
        txtNombreMateria.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
        btnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                conexion = Conexion.conectar();
                try{
                    preparedStatement = conexion
                            .prepareStatement("Select nombre_materia from materias where id_materias = ?");

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, txtldMateria.getText());
                    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    if (resultSet.next()){
                        txtNombreMateria.setText(resultSet.getString("nombre_materia"));
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo de materio no encontrado");
                    }
                    conexion.close();
                }catch (SQLException e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error con el acceso a la base de datos");
                }
            }
        });
        btnBuscar.setBounds(198, 75, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnBuscar);

        JButton btnAgregar = new JButton("Agregar");
        btnAgregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                conexion = Conexion.conectar();

                try {
                    preparedStatement = conexion
                            .prepareStatement("Insert into materias (id_materia, nombre_materia) values (?,?)");

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, txtldMateria.getText());
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, txtNombreMateria.getText());

                    int resultado = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    if (resultado > 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Registro agregado");
                        limpiarCuadrosDeTexto();
                        conexion.close();
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "No se pudo agregar registro");
                    }

                }catch(SQLException e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "ocurrio un fallo en la bbdd");
                }
            }

            private void limpiarCuadrosDeTexto() {


            }
        });
        btnAgregar.setBounds(10, 215, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAgregar);

        JButton btnBorrar = new JButton("Borrar");
        btnBorrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                conexion = Conexion.conectar();
                try{
                    preparedStatement = conexion
                            .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Materias Where id_materia = ? ");
                    preparedStatement.setString(1,  txtldMateria.getText());

                int resultado = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                if (resultado > 0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro eliminado correctamente");
                    limpiarCuadrosDeTexto();
                    conexion.close();
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo eliminar registro");
                }
                }catch(SQLException e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error al acceso de la bbdd");
                }
            }
        });
        btnBorrar.setBounds(201, 215, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnBorrar);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("modificar");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                conexion = Conexion.conectar();
                try{
                    preparedStatement = conexion
                            .prepareStatement("UPDATE Materias SET nombre_materia = ? Where id_materia = ? ");

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, txtNombreMateria.getText());
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, txtldMateria.getText());

                    int resultado = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    if (resultado > 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro modificado correctamente");
                    }

                }catch (SQLException e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error de acceso a la base de datos");
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(102, 215, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnSalir = new JButton("Salir");
        btnSalir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
        btnSalir.setBounds(313, 215, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSalir);
    }
}
```

Comment: qué base de datos? que versión? qué mensaje de error te aparece? Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1-xBYsPmoz35hpK3pm2kLDZWFTTCqbh-J


Ahi tienes el error que me sale , cada vez que escribo cualquier cosa para buscar por el "id de la materia" me da un error de la base de datos se que no es me he asegurado

Comment: dice que necesito acceso, podrías agregar el mensaje de error a tu pregunta?

Comment: Basicamente que cada vez que le doy a buscar me salta un error que dice ocurrio algo con el acceso a la base de datos

Comment: y cual es el error que te sale en el mensaje programado? Porque algún detsalle del error deberías de estar imprimiendo no(e1.getCause())?